# How to deal with manager who keep leading project into wrong directions?

Tags: teamwork, motivation, team-role, morale, japan

My current situation is as follow:

---

1. i work in a software company, mainly focus on embedded system. i moved into current company in 2016 and started as fresh-man at division X.
2. The current project was started 8 months ago. Because the Y division did not have enough people so they borrow me and an senior-engineer A.

The relationships between us is as follow

manager B : team manager

|

senior-engineer A : team leader

|

me : developer

3. my task is developing OCR module. I can design the entire module by my-self. And the design itself have to be reviewed by the senior-engineer A and the manager B. But the problem is instead of let me design the module, the manager keep taking advice from other people and design by himself. Those design are the worst. So even-though i was said to him several times, both of them didn't listen. And the disaster happened, the module barely reach 10% of the requirement

5 months was lost and they finally use my original design which were showed to them 5 months ago. I only have 3 months so it only reach 70% of the requirement. I said to them that i need another 2 months to reach 100%.

3. Because of personal things, i took 2 weeks off. And when i came back, the manager B change the design again which should lead us into same disaster. And i can do nothing about it. Which was a shock.

---

I felt that they didn't recognize my effort and let me down.
So how can i deal with this situation ? Should i keep alert them ? And moreover how can i motivate myself through this type of situations?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What's your team leader doing about this?

Comment: Sorry i miss that part. Somehow the team leader and team manager is in the same boat. At first  the manager and leader secretly work on the design by themselves. After it failed, i have to directly go to talk with the manager. And the worst part is the team leader did not know whether me or the manager is correct. So he did hide my design and choose the manager.

Answer (score 4):

When working in contemporary corporate cultures the most important rule is CYA.

CYA = cover your ass

If your manager asks you to do B instead of A - which you think is the correct solution, you write them an email. You write that in your opinion A is correct and that you understand he wants you to do B instead. You ask him to correct you if you are wrong.

If afterwards you are told you did it wrong and should have gone for A you forward the person the email thus proving it wasn't your idea to go for B.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So that mean i should only alert the manager once (in email) and let him deal with that?